# PC Time in variable should not change while the programm is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to get the PC time only once and then it should never change as long as the programm is processing. Imagine the following:

```
dynamic_pctime = strftime("%H:%M").replace(":", ";")
```

To get the PC time in 10;43 as example. So as long as the programm is running it should stay at 10;43 when i am accessing this variable.

How do I save the time so that it doesn't change within the program as long as the program is running?

Example:

```
dynamic_pctime = strftime("%H:%M").replace(":", ";")


ExamplePath = r"C:/Example/Example2"+str(static_pctime)+""

def worker(device):

if device is None:
 print ("Device not found")
 f = open(ExamplePath + "Devicelist.txt", "w")
 f.write("Device not found") + "\r\n")
 f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if os.path.exists(ExamplePath):
        print("")
    else:
        os.mkdir(ExamplePath)
        print("Path created")
```

So we create a folder with the time 11:11 as example. So when the worker is accessing the path he is automatically asking the dynamic_pctime what time he has stored. And tries to store the file into the folder with the time he got for example 11:12 instead of 11:11.

So every Worker gets a different time and tries to store in a folder which dont exists.

Comment: Variables don't change, unless assigned to, which makes it unclear what your problem with that is. Also, if you give example code, please make sure people can grab it and run it, your code isn't even syntactically correct (messed up indentation).

Answer (score 0):

With your latest update, it seems that the Python script is by another "master" application. And it might hint at a possibility to improve the overall architecture. But without knowing more about the "master" program, it is hard to say.

If that is the case, it is up to that "master" program to pass the time to the Python script.

One important this is that `datetime.now()` will always return the *current* time. The only way to have the time "frozen" is by saving the value somewhere. If everything runs in the same process it can be a variable. If - like seemingly in your case - is spans multiple distinct processes, you might need to save the value into persisten storage (like plain-text) file. But this opens up risks of race-conditions (what if two processes run at the same time and want to create the same file twice). It is a fragile approach. I would only do this if absolutely necessary.

A slightly better approach is to have the master-application deal with this alone and pass the values as arguments to the sub-processes.

Again, as the detail of the master application is missing I am forced to take an educated guess. That guess is that the master program is a bash-script executing the other processes (I might be wrong).

So inside the Python script you need to read the value from the CLI argument. This can be done by accessing `sys.argv` but I *STRONGLY* suggest using `argparse` instead. It is only marginally more work but *WAY* more maintainable (and it gives you a `--help` argument for free):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('starttime')
    return parser.parse_args()

cli_args = parse_args()
timestring = cli_args.starttime
```

Next, the "master" application needs to pass this value into the child script:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 mychildproc.py 11:11 &
python3 mychildproc.py 11:11 &
python3 mychildproc.py 11:11 &
python3 mychildproc.py 11:11 &
python3 mychildproc.py 11:11 &
python3 mychildproc.py 11:11 &

wait
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am working with multiprocessing. And each worker calls this time variable even with your solution the time changes.

Comment: That is indeed an important detail ;)

Comment: I have updated the answer for multiprocessing. However, without having an example of your code it is unlikely that it resembles your code. The idea is the same htough: store the value in a variable and then pass it to the subprocesses.

Comment: so i edited my question properly and i am apologising to you for the inconvience i had done to you. I should have provided my code or an example how i structured it. I hope you help me nevertheless

Comment: I have updated again with your latest info. Again, it is missing some information so I had to guess again.